# TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take a column from a dataset and set it to a variable. The dataset has multiple columns, but the one I need is the 'ID' column.

If you look at my code below, you will see that I am using tkinter to create an app and ask the user to upload a dataset (which will contain the 'ID' column). Then the code will read the file and extract the 'ID' column. The line that is giving me the error is:

```
ids = int(data['ID'])
```

The error is telling me that the series (or column) needs to be all integer values and not string, which is why I am using the 'int()' function, but it is still giving me this error:

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import delete as dl
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk() 

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300) 
canvas1.pack()


from tkinter import filedialog
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    data = file.read()
    ids = int(data['ID'])
    file.close()
```

Comment: i think the `TypeError` refers to the index `['ID']` and not to `data`. So your type conversion does nothing. Also it says that `data` is of `byte` type and not a `dict` type.

Comment: `"The error is telling me that the series (or column) needs to be all integer values ad not string,"` what? That's not what the error is telling you. The error is  saying that `data` is of type `bytes`, and you can only _slice_ a bytes object using integer or slices (i.e. you can only do `data[1]` or `data[1:]`), but not with strings (i.e. you cannot do `data['ID']`. Clearly, `data` is not what you think it is. I'm not familiar with `askopenfile` but investigate what it is that it returns

Answer (score 0):

Calling `data['ID']` would return something if `data` were a dictionary with an `'ID'` key, but `data = file.read()` returns a string (or bytes) object.

What format is the dataset being uploaded as? If it's a text/csv file, you might be able to use `csv.DictReader` (more at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

@ahanson was on the money.

I am not sure exactly how '.read()' works, but it seems to open the file as a bytes object. I instead switch that with pd.read_excel() and that works.

New code that works:

```
import tkinter as tk
import delete as dl
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk() 

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300) 
canvas1.pack()


from tkinter import filedialog
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    data = pandas.read_excel(file)
    ids = data['ID']
```